# Ruby while loop within if statement

Tags: ruby

Using the following code in Ruby:

```
if (tickFormat.length > 12 && tickFormat.length < 24)
    i = 1
    while(i < tickFormat.length) do
        if (i%2 != 0)
          tickFormat.at(i)[1] = ''
        end
        i++
    end
end
```

I get an "unexpected keyword_end" for the 2nd "end" statement.  If I remove the while loop the code runs without error.  Any ideas?

Comment: There's no `i++` in Ruby.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this question was down-voted so that I don't make the same mistake in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (tickFormat.length > 12 && tickFormat.length < 24)
  i = 1
  while(i < tickFormat.length) do
    if (i%2 != 0)
      tickFormat.at(i)[1] = ''
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```

The `i++` syntax doesn't work in Ruby

Comment: Probably because there's no such thing in Ruby :p

Answer (score 3):

You're obviously from the C corner so some additional info from my side:

First I would like to quote [Alexey Anufriyev](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/27268)

> I think you should use naming convention adopted by your platform. underscore_case will look weird in C# code, as camelCase in Ruby =)

So you should consider using underscore notation.

Also you're code is pretty C style. This is a bit more ruby like (though it is a matter of taste whether you write short statements in the same line or not):

```
if tick_format.length === (13..23)
  tick_format.each_with_index do |tf, i|
    tf[1] = '' if i.odd?
  end
end

# if you use active support's core extensions (which is recommended imho)
# you can rewrite line 1 as:
if tick_format.length.in? 13..23
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has too much sugar to code it C-style :)

Try something like

```
if tickFormat.length.between?(13,23)
  (1..tickFormat.length).step(2) do |i|
    tickFormat.at(i)[1] = ''
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use i+=1 to increment.

```
if tickFormat.length > 12 && tickFormat.length < 24
        i = 1
        while i < tickFormat.length do
            if (i%2 != 0)
              tickFormat.at(i)[1] = ''
            end
            i+=1
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong is the `i++`. I might suggest migrating the style a bit from C-like to canonical-Ruby, but that's just a personal choice...

```
if (13..23) === tickFormat.length
  i = 1
  while i < tickFormat.length
    if i % 2 != 0
      tickFormat.at(i)[1] = ''
    end
    i += 1
  end
end
```